# How to receive messages via wifi while running main program in ESP32?

Tags: esp32, platformio

Ive incorporated multiple features i want in a microcontroller program (ESP32 Wroom32) and needed some advice on the best way to keep the program running and receive messages while it is running.

Current code:

```
//includes and declarations
setup()
{
//setup up wifi, server
}

main(){

WiFiClient client = server.available();
byte new_command[40];

if (client)                         // If client object is created, a connection is setup
   {                            
   Serial.println("New wifi Client.");           
   String currentLine = "";         //Used to print messages
   while (client.connected())
      {

      recv_byte = client.read();
      new_command = read_incoming(&recv_byte, client); //Returns received command and check for format. If invalid, returns a 0 array
      if (new_command[0] != 0) //Checks if message is not zero, None of valid messages start with zero
      {
       execute_command(new_command);
       //new_command is set to zero
      }
      }//end of while loop
   }//end of if loop
}
```

The downside of this is that the ESP32 waits till the command is finished executing before it is ready to receive a new message. It is desired that the ESP32 receive commands and store them, and execute it at its own pace. I am planning to change the current code to receive a messages while the code is running as follows:

```
main()
{
WiFiClient client = server.available();
byte new_command[40];
int command_count = 0;
byte command_array[50][40];

if (command_count != 0)
      {
       execute_command(command_array[0]);
       //Decrement command_count
       //Shift all commands in command_array by 1 row above
       //Set last executed command to zero
      }
}//end of main loop

def message_interrupt(int recv_byte, WiFiClient& running_client)
{
   If (running_client.connected())
      {
      recv_byte = running_client.read();
      new_command = read_incoming(&recv_byte, running_client); //Returns received command and check for format. If invalid, returns a 0 array
      //add new command to command_array after last command
      //increment command_count
      }
}
```

Which interrupt do I use to receive the message and update the command_array ? https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/wifi.html Doesnt mention any receive/transmit events. I couldnt find any receive/transmit interrupt either or maybe I searched for the wrong term.

Comment: What about using multiple tasks (search for task)? One polling and storing the commands while another processes the requests? Interrupts are normally intended for really short actions and not for complex control flow like "polling-access mutex-storing".

Comment: Some commands are fast (few seconds), others can take upto 3 hours to finish. The message itself is no more than 40 bytes (320 bits = 0.32 milliseconds at max). 

Polling is used to check GPIO status and take actions as far as I understand, such as check if a sensor has output ready. Im not aware how to you use polling then way you are implying here

Comment: If you are not very used to interrupt usage on µC and its implication I would strongly advise against its use. Tasks should be actually the thing you are looking for.

Comment: ESP32 has 2 cores.